# What's the reason for the deadlock between China and the Phillipines over oil exploitation issues in the South China Sea?

Tags: china, philippines

> **"We are still at a deadlock right now," Marcos said as he emphasised
> his country's right to exploit energy reserves in the West Philippines
> Sea at a time the Philippines wants to reduce its reliance on fossil
> fuel and coal and transition to liquified natural gas.**
>
> Manila refers to the portion of the South China Sea that is within its
> Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ) as the West Philippine Sea.
>
> Efforts to find a legally viable way to cooperate on energy
> exploration have stalled repeatedly, with previous administration
> abandoning talks in June last year citing constitutional constraints
> and issues of sovereignty.

https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/philippines-marcos-says-tensions-south-china-sea-have-increased-2023-12-17/

What's the reason for the deadlock between China and the Phillipines over oil exploitation issues in the South China Sea? They mention there's a deadlock, but they don't mention what both sides don't agree upon. Was there any statement specifying what's causing the negotiations to be in a deadlock state between the two countries? What are both sides asking?

Comment: Both sides claim some of the areas under consideration as exclusively theirs and neither is willing to budge. What else do you expect?

Comment: What quarague said, plus the territorial disputes bring an extra dimension of stalemate.  Unlike say Timor Leste and Australia, which about $$$, both parties would see oil agreements as recognizing some form of the other party' territorial claims.  Countries hate to take *any* steps which might recognize some official status to a claim they reject, sometimes to a ridiculous, theatrical, extent.

Comment: The question seems to answer itself. I'm not sure what the real question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question:**
>
> What's the reason for the deadlock between China and the Philippines over oil exploitation issues in the South China Sea?

Generally, according to the 1982 United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea,  every country is entitled to 12 miles of territorial waters.  Waters which it controls and others may not enter without permission.  In addition generally, countries have the rights to 200 nautical miles (230 miles) of Exclusive Economic Zone.  In this zone beyond it's territorial waters countries have the exclusive rights to develop the resources, (fishing, minerals etc)  but other countries have the right to peacefully transit through.

So here is the dispute.  Beginning in 2013 China started building 7 artificial islands most inside the Philippine's 200 mile Exclusive Economic Zone all nearly 1000 miles removed from China's own Exclusive Economic Zone.  China has claimed historic rights to these waters siteing maps many hundreds of years old.  China has populated and militarized these new artificial islands and is claiming each of these islands is entitled to it's own territorial waters, and it's own Exclusive Economic Zone.  Under a previous Philippines administration this issue was heard at a UN arbitrators panel at the Hague specializing in the laws of the sea.

In July of 2016 this arbitration body sided overwhelmingly with the Philippines.   Asserting that China basically piled coral and rocks on top of one another to manufacture their "Islands".  That these islands don't have natural fresh water, can't support life, and thus can not be claimed as territory.  ( no internationally recognized EEZ ).  They remain just rocks.  Likewise the Hague found their historical claims unconvincing and dismissed them.   China responded by largely ignoring the Hague.

So why did the compromise talks on exploiting oil and natural gas rights collapse?   The Philippines would very much like to exploit oil and natural gas deposits in their EEZ, they are not particularly motivated to share these rights with China.  On the other hand China would also like to develop these resources.  What's standing in the way of a compromise is each side is looking to get some leverage for the merits of their own claims and are hesitant to enter an agreement which bolsters the others claims.  In addition to that the Philippines has defense treaties with the United States, Japan, and Australia.   They regularly conduct freedom of navigation drills inside what  china is claiming as it's islands territorial waters.   So china blocking compromise is a way for China to show it's displeasure with the Philippines activities with it's allies.